# Compile .java file with external dependecy into .class file

Tags: java, class, compiler-errors, compilation

I have the following **External.java** file that has an external dependency on JAsioHost.jar file placed in folderWhereMyJarIs:

[image]

```
package external;

import com.synthbot.jasiohost.*;

public class External {

public External(){
    System.out.println("Class CONSTRUCTOR");
}

public int operateAdd(int a, int b){
    int res = a+b;
    return res;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello world");
} 

}
```

I am having trouble compiling the .java file into .class file from my Windows command line because when I type

```
javac -cp .;/folderWhereMyJarIs/JAsioHost.jar External.java
```

it gives me the following error:

```
package com.synthbot.jasiohost does not exist
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to use backslashes in the path to your JAR?

Comment: `javac -cp .;./folderWhereMyJarIs/JAsioHost.jar External.java`

Comment: @shadowsheep that solved the issue, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @shadowsheep in his helpful comment, I answer my own question posting the solution that works just fine:

```
javac -cp .;./folderWhereMyJarIs/JAsioHost.jar External.java
```

Hope this will help others